# Does the following Series diveges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I encountered an infinite series $S=\sum_2^{\infty}{\frac{k-1}{k^2lnk}}$. I have to show whether it converges or diverges. I split it into two other sums as fallows:
$\sum_2^{\infty}{\frac{k-1}{k^2lnk}}$
$=\sum_2^{\infty}{\frac{1}{klnk}}-\sum_2^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2lnk}}$.
I used integral test and found that the first one on RHS converges. Then since the second one on the RHS is less than the first one on the specified interval so it should also converge. But when I used a calculator and calculated the series using more and more terms each time, it actually got bigger and bigger. Is there any thing wrong with me.

Comment: The first one on the right diverges, integral test. The second converges. Note that an antiderivative  of $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$ is $\ln(\ln x)$.

Comment: @André Nicolas No it converges.

Comment: No, it doesn't converge.

Comment: @André Nicolas oh I see it.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\log(n)}\ge \int_2^N \frac{1}{x\log(x)}\,dx\to \infty$$

Comment: @Dr. MV It is very interesting to note that since in calculus books it is given that the series of the form $\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{k^n}$ converges for all valves of n except 1, and here we have $lnk$ in the denomenator and it diverges.

Comment: Maybe it is also interesting for you that $\sum\frac 1 {k\log^\alpha(k)}$ converges for any $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: Well, recall that for any $\alpha>0$, $\log(x)\le \frac{x^{\alpha}-1}{\alpha}$.  So, $\log(x)$ grows more slowly than any positive power of $x$.  So, perhaps it is not so surprising.  But this inequality does not show the divergence of the series of interest.  Rather, it provides only some intuition as to why the series might not converge.  The result from the integral test is definitive.